# Java (or Android) version of setting particular parts of Mat in OpenCV

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

I have the following part of code in C++.

```
cv::Mat markers(image.size(),CV_8U,cv::Scalar(-1));
markers(cv::Rect(0,0,image.cols, 5)) = cv::Scalar::all(1);
```

Can anybody tell me what is the equivalent syntax in Java (or android) version of this part of the code. I was looking at "setTo()" but it doesn't seem to take Rect. Or I can only modify one by one through a loop?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that come to mind.

1. Use **submat**

   `markers.submat(new Rect(0,0,image.cols(),5)).setTo(new Scalar(1));`
2. Use **rowRange** and **colRange**

   `markers.rowRange(0,5).colRange(0,image.cols()).setTo(new Scalar(1));`